Convert uShort[] into Color bitmap image in c#
I have ushort[] array, value lies from 0 to 700. I need to create a color image (Jetmap) out of this array using bitmaps. Below is the code I tried but could not get fine image. How can I create a color image from a 1D array>
public Bitmap getColorBitmap(ushort[] arr, int xL, int yL)
{
            var bitmap = new Bitmap(xL, yL, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format48bppRgb);
            int count = 0;
            for (y = 0; y < xL; y++)
            {
                for (x = 0; x < yL; x++)
                {
                    Color g = JetColor(arr[count], 0, 255);
                    bitmap.SetPixel(x, y, g);
                    count++;
                }
            }
    return bitmap;
}

        public static Color JetColor(float v, float vmin, float vmax)
        {
            float r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;
            float x = (v - vmin) / (vmax - vmin);
            r = 255 * Constrain(-4 * Math.Abs(x-0.75f) + 2f, 0, 1);
            g = 255 * Constrain(-4 * Math.Abs(x - 0.50f) + 2f, 0, 1);
            b = 255 * Constrain(-4 * Math.Abs(x) + 2, 0, 1);
            return Color.FromArgb((int)r, (int)g, (int)b);
        }

        private static float Constrain(float value, float min, float max)
        {
            return Math.Max(min, Math.Min(max, value));
        }


Please do not add irrelevant tags. I do not see how this has anything to do with [tag:matlab].

@Adriaan I guess the OP means the jet colormap of matlab, I couldn't find a general explanation for Jetmap/JetColor on the Internet.

If "value lies from 0 to 700", why did you divide it by 255?

This library  (discmaimer: written by me) supports creating bitmaps using custom pixel format and allows using any kind of array as a back buffer. If you don't mind using a 3rd party library, and cannot find ouy how to use it, let me know if you want me to provide an answer.

Format48bppRgb or other high dynamic range pixel formats rarely work well, since very few display system handle them appropriately. Most seem to simply take the top 8/10/12 bits, usually resulting in horrible contrast.
So you most likely want to convert the image to a lower dynamic range yourself. Start by creating a 8 bit (Format8bppIndexed) bitmap. Create a BitmapPalette  for your palette, and assign this to your image.
The most complicated part of this is the conversion to 8 bits, the typical way to do this is using unsafe code for better performance:
var height = yL;
var width = xL;
var bitmapData = myBitmap.LockBits(
    new Rectangle(0, 0,width , height ),
    ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
    myBitmap.PixelFormat);


try
{
    fixed(ushort* source = arr)
    {
        var target = (byte*)bitmapData.Scan0;
        var targetStride = bitmapData.Stride;
        // The range of values in the source data
        var fMin = 0;
        var fMax = 700;
        
        // the range of values in the target, use a lower tMax if you palette does not cover the full 0-255 range of a byte. 
        var tMax = byte.MaxValue;
        var tMin = 0;
        var slope = ((tMax  - tMin ) + 1f) / (fMax  - fMin );
        Parallel.For(0, height, y =>
            {
                var ySource = source + y * width;
                var yTarget = target + y * targetStride;
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    var sample = ySource [x];
                    var scaled = (int)(((sample + 0.5 - fMin) * slope)) + tMin;
                    scaled = scaled > tMax ? tMax : scaled;
                    scaled = scaled < tMin ? tMin : scaled;
                    yTarget[x] = (byte)scaled;
                }
            });
    }
}
finally
{
    buffer.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
}

Constructing the bitmap palette is left as an exercise. If you specifically want a rgb32 image in the end you would just create an array with a color for each 8 bit value, use the 8 bit value for each pixel as the index to get a 32 bit color, and adjust the pixel format and pointer type accordingly.
In many cases you would also want to compute the fMin and fMax values from the source image, since it may vary. In some cases you might want to ignore extreme values in either direction so that a single bright or dark pixel do not destroy the output contrast. Or use something even more advanced like historgram equalization.
